# Fill selection with select more via Python

Tags: python, select

I want to fill out the selection I have. So from the active face I want to **select more** a lot and deselect the normal selection after every iteration.
How often it should use the **select more** command is not important, since my selection that I give should stop the **select more** command from selecting to much.

[image]

So the script should do this:

1. From my selection it selects only the active face
2. Selects More command
3. Deselects my selection I started with except the active face
4. Repeat 2. to 3. for x times

I could not do it. I tried it with bmesh but I don't understand how it works.

Here is my code so far:

```
import bpy

growAmount = 30
obj = bpy.context.active_object
if bpy.context.object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

selectedFaces = []
activeFace = obj.data.polygons[obj.data.polygons.active]

for i in obj.data.polygons:
    if i.select:
        if i.index != activeFace.index:
            selectedFaces.append(i.index)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for i in selectedFaces:
    obj.data.polygons[i].select = False

for i in range(growAmount):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_more(use_face_step=False)
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    for i in selectedFaces:
        obj.data.polygons[i].select = False

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
```

It works okay but leaves edges selected that I don't want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not the ideal code solution but it works:

```
import bpy

growAmount = 30
obj = bpy.context.active_object
if bpy.context.object.mode == 'EDIT':
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

selectedFaces = []
selectedEdges = []

activeFace = obj.data.polygons[obj.data.polygons.active]

for i in obj.data.polygons:
    if i.select:
        if i.index != activeFace.index:
            selectedFaces.append(i.index)

for i in obj.data.edges:
    if obj.data.edges[i.index].select:
        selectedEdges.append(i.index)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for i in selectedFaces:
    obj.data.polygons[i].select = False

for i in selectedEdges:
    obj.data.edges[i].select = False

for i in range(growAmount):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    for i in selectedFaces:
        obj.data.polygons[i].select = False
    for i in selectedEdges:
        obj.data.edges[i].select = False

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='EDGE')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(use_extend=False, use_expand=False, type='FACE')
```